# Is it possible to access the custom settings which are not part of the manage packaged?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have installed manage package on my client's org and we are storing service charge's in the custom-setting and it's part of managed package. whatever the fields created initially in this setting are getting accessed in the packaged apex code. but if client create's a new service charge on his own org independently (Obviously it will not be part of manage package) it's not getting accessed in packaged apex code. is there any workaround for this?

Thanks any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand u right but as far as I get this you want your clients to set some different value into a custom settings field that the one that you pre-define within the managed package right?
So we use this like the following in Apex:
e.g. for a Boolean

```
Boolean b = Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().get('NameOfField');
```

Here the Settings__c are Protected as well as Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If you want apex code outside of your managed package to access a custom setting defined in your managed package, I believe you have to make the custom setting public.